# any method to show user location in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Is there any method that take latitude and longitude as parameter and google map link or apple map link these three parameter to show user location on google map or apple map so user can use google created google map functionality like arrow direction or zoom in/out.

I don't want to use MKMapView of iOS to show user location in my app.

thanks in advance give me any cool method(latitude,longitude,google map link)as parameter.

Comment: This question is very vague, and you've demonstrated no effort on your part to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For coordinates only, you need CoreLocation, so google that.

But if you need to show a map and arrow, you do need a maps framework. Either go for built in MKMapKit, or you can download Google Maps SDK.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , Please import this framework

**#import** 
 , to import this framework , you need to select your project then go to build phases , click on **link binaries with libraries** and add the **core location framework** .

Add this code in your view controller in **view didload** method:-

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // 100 m
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

// Delegates of Mapview

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
[map_View setRegion:[map_View regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
if (newLocation != nil) {
    NSLog(@"%f %f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager = nil;
}

// Reverse Geocoding
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [CLGeocoder new];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
                placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
            }
        } ];

    });
```

}

Don't forget to add this line in your **plist** file :-

**NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**